# Weblogic managed server fails to start: "access denied com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax"

Tags: weblogic

I've got a Weblogic managed server that I'm having problems starting when I add -Djava.security.manager to JAVA_OPTIONS. If I remove it then I have no problems starting up the server, even without my app deployed.

The error I am getting is:

```
<Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.MissingResourceException: Could not instantiate factory delegate, got exception(s):
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax")
```

By trial and error I have found that I can start successfully by adding this:

```
grant codeBase "file:/app/weblogic/weblogic_12c/oracle_common/modules/-" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

to the weblogic.policy file.

I don't understand what there is in that directory that is causing me problems that are solved by this! It is contains over 100 jars that were installed by weblogic, I assume that one of them is responsible for my problem.

I've checked all of the classes in these jars (using jar -tvf) but the trax package doesn't appear anywhere.

I'd rather not leave the policy file with such a wide permission set, so any suggestions would be helpful.

EDIT:
Additional info:
    SunOS 5.10
    Weblogic 12c
    Java 1.7.0_45

Comment: Do you have the xalan.jar packaged in your webapp? Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621253/appengine-error-java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-lan

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp - thanks for replying, unfortunately I haven't even deployed my app, this is just an empty server. Worked OK on our previous version of weblogic but it's not clear if there were some tweaks done to it to get it working.

Comment: I have the same problem and identical exception. I also had to add  grant to "/oracle_common/modules/-" in order to launch the server. But I am still stuck with "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory could not be instantiated" - Have you found a solution ? (Windows, Java 1.7.0_45, WL 12c.)